# Pass dynamic value to php and get date

Tags: php, jquery, date

```
var dt = 6;
var dtyp = M;
```

need to pass this values to `strtotime` in php to get date after 6 months `if dtyp = D` need to add 6 days to current date, `if dtyp = Y` need to add 6 years to current date.

```
<?php echo date("d/m/Y", strtotime("+6 days"));?> 

$.each(data.response.duration,function(a,b){
    var dt = b.exp_dur;
    var dtyp = b.exp_type;
    $('.after_dat').val('<?php echo date("d/m/Y", strtotime("+.'dt'. days"));?>')
});
```

`dt` and `dtyp` will be dynamic getting from db.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking here, or what the code you've posted is suppose to do. Please clarify your question, the flow and show us what you've actually tried.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson sorry for bad english.Need pass vale from jquery to php

Comment: You're English seems fine. The question just lacks proper information. If you just need to pass data from js to php, use ajax: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

```
                             if(b.exp_type === 'D'){
                                $('.after_dat').val('');
                                var date = new Date();
                                futr =  parseInt(b.exp_dur)
                                date.setDate(date.getDate() +futr);
                                var dateMsg = date.getDate()+'/'+ (date.getMonth()+1) +'/'+date.getFullYear();
                                // alert(dateMsg);
                                $('.after_dat').val(dateMsg);
                            }
                            if(b.exp_type === 'M'){
                                $('.after_dat').val('');
                                futr =  parseInt(b.exp_dur)
                                var jan312009 = new Date();
                                var eightMonthsFromJan312009 = new Date(new Date(jan312009).setMonth(jan312009.getMonth()+futr));
                                var dateMsg = eightMonthsFromJan312009.getDate()+'/'+ (eightMonthsFromJan312009.getMonth()+1) +'/'+eightMonthsFromJan312009.getFullYear();
                                $('.after_dat').val(dateMsg);

                            }
                            if(b.exp_type === 'Y'){
                                $('.after_dat').val('');
                                futr =  parseInt(b.exp_dur)
                                var jan312009 = new Date();
                                var eightMonthsFromJan312009 = new Date(new Date(jan312009).setFullYear(jan312009.getFullYear()+futr));
                                var dateMsg = eightMonthsFromJan312009.getDate()+'/'+ (eightMonthsFromJan312009.getMonth()+1) +'/'+eightMonthsFromJan312009.getFullYear();
                                $('.after_dat').val(dateMsg);

                            }
```